# Django problem with delete the file after calling it in the view

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I'm struggling with the following problem. In my application I have a model containing an `InputFile()` field. In this field, it stores `.mat` files, which then I open in the view using methods from the scipy library.

I have also implemented a mechanism to delete records from the database, along with files uploaded to the server. It works until I try to open the file from `InputFile()` and load data from it. Then, when I try to delete a record with this file, I get a message that this .mat file is being used by another process. How to do it so that the 'connection' to the file will end after saving its contents in the variable in the view?

I will be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was less complicated than it seemed.

- Call the instance of file eg. `data.input_file`
- Use methods to load data from a file
- Call the `.close()` method on the file instance.